# Запрос на формирование таблицы отчета

Tags: php, kohana, фреймворк

Есть такая таблица отчетов по датам

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спомощью запроса (в модели)

```
$query = DB::select('id', 'date', 'content', array(DB::expr('year(`date`)'), 'year'))
                    ->from('reports')
                    ->where('activity_id', '=', $ID)
                    ->order_by('date', 'DESC');
```

Получил данные,
Но теперь мне их нужно вывести в шаблон, таким образом
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Т.е. создать список, в котором «год» нужно выводить только один раз на все отчеты, созданные в конкретном году.
Циклом `<?php foreach($list_reports as $key => $list_report):?>`
Я могу перебрать и вывести, только получается выводить год к каждой статье.
Вопрос заключается в том, что нужно ли переделывать сам запрос или получаемый массив?

Comment: Написал процедуру, которая меняет ключи массива, перед этим, скопровав существующий массив (результат запроса) в другую переменную **$editList = $query;**, но когда доходит начинает работать процедура, валится ошибка **Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Database results are read-only**

Comment: Поскольку речь идет о raw запросе, думаю, можно добавить в него колонку с годом.

Comment: так колонка с "годом" (**array(DB::expr('year(`date`)'), 'year')**), уже есть. Теперь **задача**, в view, выводить его только **один** раз

Comment: Извини, не заметил. Ну тогда тут только кастомный грид писать, лучше не придумаешь.

Comment: Андрей@, что ты имеешь в виду под "кастомный грид"? наводку дай пожалуйста. И можешь подсказать, как я могу скопировать $query, в другую переменную - чтобы можно изменять (это же массив)

Comment: Ну, под гридом я имею ввиду таблицу для отображения данных - общепринятый термин в сленге. Кастомный - значит, реализованный под конкретные нужды. Если есть необходимость копировать `$query` - значит что-то пошло не так )) Вообще, не знаю, как в kohana, но если в `$query` объект запроса, то запрос обычно составляется последовательно, условиями, к примеру, если в `$request` пришла дата начала периода - указываем ее в `$query` и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($list_reports as $key => $list_report): ?>
    ...
    <? if(!array_key_exists($list_report['year']), $years): ?>
        <?= $list_report['year'] ?>
        ...
        <? $years[$list_report['year']] = true; ?>
        ...
    <? endif; ?>
    ...
```

Comment: **Спасибо** Андрей - помогло...С дополнительным массивом в view, я не додумался бы (привык, что все php в контроллере выполнять). Правда, небольшая запинка была с "$years", но потом в контроллере создал пустой массив "$years" и передпл его в view.

Comment: я лишь подал идею, и ты ее понял правильно )